# Why autoboxing is not supporting in collection.toArray() in java

Tags: java, arrays, collections

Is there no any short cut to do this nicely?

That ugly two loops (One loop to read the pmList and second loop to add to the markupArray) is the only option (Instead of ArrayUtils).

```
ArrayList<Double> pmList = new ArrayList<Double>();     
pmList.add(0.1); // adding through a loop in real time.
pmList.add(0.1);
pmList.add(0.1);
pmList.add(0.1);

double[] markupArray = new double[pmList.size()];
arkupArray = pmList.toArray(markupArray); // This says The method toArray(T[]) in the type ArrayList<Double> is not applicable for the arguments (double[])
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use a `Double[]` array, instead of `double[]` then everything works fine. If you know the size of the list ahead of time, you can also skip the list and insert directly into the array. It might even be worth to traverse the input two times: Once for retrieving its size and once for insertion.

Auto boxing only works for primitive types, not for *arrays of primitive types*. A `double[]` array is no `T[]` array, since a type parameter `T` must always be an `Object`. While a `double` may be autoboxed to `T` (with `T=Double`), a `double[]` cannot be autoboxed to `T[]`.

The reason why arrays are not autoboxed is probably that this operation would be very costly: Boxing an array means creating a new array and boxing each element. For large arrays, this has a huge performance hit. You don't want such a costly operation to be done implicitly, hence no autoboxing for arrays. In addition, boxing a complete array would yield a new array. Thus, when writing to the new array, the changes would not write through to the old array. So you see, there are some semantics problems with array-boxing, so it is not supported.

If you must return a `double[]` array, then your must either write your own function or use a third-party library like Guava (see msandiford's answer). The Java Collections framework has no methods for (un)boxing of arrays.

Comment: @Jayaprasad: Yes, see my edited answer. Boxing simply does not work on arrays.

Comment: @ gexicide : I can't because of the dependancies. That  markupArray should be double[].

Comment: @Namalak: Do you know the size of the list ahead of time? If so, you can just skip the list and insert directly into the array.

Comment: @ gexicide : NO. (unfortunatly)

Comment: @Namalak: Well, then write your own method. The four lines won't kill you :). Another solution would be to loop twice over your input, the first time only counting the number of doubles. Is this feasible?

Comment: @gexicide Your answer on why the boxing cannot be applied is unfortunately wrong. Boxing is a compile-time feature and does not go well with generics.

Comment: @raphw: What is wrong about it? Autoboxing is done at compile time (i.e., the boxing operation is inserted at compile time) but incurs cost at runtime (the boxing itself!).

Comment: @raphw: And btw: Usual boxing does work with generics! I can surely put a `double` into a generic method `<T> void foo(T t)`. So the problem are not the generics; the problem is that autoboxing is not supported for arrays. If it was, I could put a `double[]` into a `foo(T[] t)`: The array would simply be boxed to a `Double[]` and then handed to `foo`.

Comment: @gexicide You could not implicitly box a reference type as it would break referential identity. A primitive type has no identity what is a requirement for offering autoboxing. You can call `<T> void foo(T t)` with a primitive argument value as the compiler includes the boxing instruction **outside** of the generic method. From **within** the `foo` method you could however not implicitly assume `T` to be an unboxable type as the compiler cannot be sure of the actual type of `T` which needs to be represented by a single chuck of byte code. See my answer for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @raphw: Sure, I never said that boxing an array (if it existed) would retain instance identity. But if we drop this and simply define array boxing to create a new array, then op's code *would* work. I never claimed that auto-boxing an array would be a very reasonable operation :).

Comment: @gexicide: Boxing requires that `unbox(box(value)) === value`. Boxing is literally defined as putting something inside a boxing type which represents the very same value. A *boxing* of Java arrays that you describe could not fulfill this requirement. What you describe is rather a mapping than a boxing.

Comment: @raphw: Well, since boxing is only defined for primitive types, this discussion is a bit esotheric. It could even be possible to achieve what you describe by retaining an internal weak map from `Double[]` to `double[]` to get back the old array after unboxing. So it is theoretically possible to implement boxing for arrays. It is not reasonable, however :).

Answer (score 1):

You could use TDoubleArraList or guava's primitive list collection.

You could also determine the size in advance in one loop and add the values in another.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make your own shortcut?

```
static double[] doubleListToArray(List<Double> list) {
    int k = 0;
    double[] result = new double[list.size()];
    for(double value : list)
        result[k++] = value;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: That is only displacement of the code. Are you going to say that if we are using a short-cut that must be do this two loops internally?

Comment: Any other shortcut will be doing this internally, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Google guava has [`Doubles#asList(...)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Doubles.html#asList%28double...%29) and [`Doubles#toArray(...)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Doubles.html#toArray%28java.util.Collection%29) which provide conversions from `double[]` to `List<Double>` and from `Collection<? extends Number>` to `double[]` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that this is not very intuitive at first look. However, this limitation is related to the way the Java language implements generic types and auto-boxing:

1. Generic types are erased at runtime. This implies that any `ArrayList<Double>` is represented by a single compiled Java class `ArrayList` which is shared with other generic representations of `ArrayList` such as for example `ArrayList<String>`. As a consequence, the compiled method `ArrayList::toArray` does not (and must not) know what generic type an instance represents as the single compiled method must be applicable for any generic type. As the elements could therefore be anything like `String` or `Double`, you need to provide an array to the method. The method can then check the type of the target array at runtime and check the elements that are filled into the array at runtime to be assignable to the array's component type. All this logic can be implemented by a single compiled method.
2. Secondly, auto-boxing and -unboxing is something that only exists at compile time. This means that the statements

   ```
   Integer i = 42;
   int j = i;
   ```

   are compiled as if you wrote

   ```
   Integer i = new Integer(42);
   int j = i.intValue();
   ```

   It is the Java compiler that adds the boxing instructions for you. The Java runtime applies a slightly different type system where boxing is not considered. As a consequence, the single compiled method `ArrayList::toArray` that we mentioned in (1) cannot know that this boxing needs to be applied as we argued that the method must be applicable for any type `T` which might not always represent a `Double`.

In theory, you could alter the implementation of `ArrayList::toArray` to explicitly checks if an array's component type and a lists element type are applicable for unboxing but this approach would result in several branches which would add quite a runtime overhead to the method. Rather, write a small utility method that specializes on the `Double` type and applies the implicit unboxing due to the specialization. An iteration over all list items suffices for this purpose, this is how the `ArrayList::toArray` is implemented as well. If your array is small, consider to use an array of boxed values `Double[]` instead of `double[]`. If your array is however large, lives long or you are restrained to primitive types in order to comply to a third-party API, use the utility. Also, look out for implementations of primitive collections if you want to ungo the overall boxing. With Java 8, use a `Stream` in order to inline the array conversion.